# Chef recipe for RoR Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, chef-infra, vagrant

Is there a chef cookbook or recipe for creating a Ruby on Rails heroku-like stack on a vagrant lucid32 (or 64).

I have tried the [vagrant-heroku](https://github.com/ejholmes/vagrant-heroku) box, but it doesn't seem come all that ready after all and felt a bit buggy* . I wonder if it would be more efficiently done some other way.

A well documented guide on how to build such stack would also do. [This guy](http://blog.bloc.io/a-better-way-to-set-up-rails-on-windows) comes pretty close, but misses all the PostgreSQL part and versions details.

*disclaimer: I am a newbie, with "bit buggy" I mean it wasn't as straight forward as I expected*

Comment: I haven't seen one, but this link may help: http://community.opscode.com/search?query=rails&scope=cookbook

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at Dokku. As far as I know, it's the closest thing out there to rolling your own Heroku.

https://github.com/progrium/dokku