# Why isn't there a chef/puppet recipe to recreate a Heroku dyno?

Tags: heroku, virtual-machine, chef-infra, puppet

I would like to setup a local instance of a Heroku dyno-like virtual machine. Given the popularity of Heroku I would have expected this to be a common request, but either no one has done this or my search skills are weak. I realize that some people just use a separate Heroku environment as their development platform, but is there another reason why there are no 'ready made' dyno construction kits for local virtualized environments like chef or puppet ?

edit: To clarify, I'm trying to build a local environment that has resource constraints that match a single Heroku dyno, not [recreate an entire paas offering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591704/chef-recipe-for-ror-heroku).

Answer (score 1):

First off, If you really want to match the resource constraints of a single dyno, why not just grab a VPS with 512MB. That's a single dyno worth of RAM, and while you won't be able specify CPU clock, you'll find a VPS is generally a bit faster than Heroku. (I've heard a dyno is about 1.8Ghz - 2.0Ghz...)

Also, you'll want to spin up a separate machine for your DB (if you need one at all), as these are separate instances on Heroku.

If you are looking for a paas offering, check out https://github.com/progrium/dokku